# JOOQ: batch CRUD operations using dynamic table definitions, how to?

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq, batching

I'm looking for a way to dynamically create CRUD queries using JOOQ.

I have a heavily partitioned table and I'd like to perform batch inserts/updates/deletes directly into the right partition. Reason is significant performance gain in my scenario.

1. I have JOOQ-generated templates for root table.
2. Partitions for this table are generated dynamically.
3. I can create a table with required schema and partition name using `DSL.table()`
4. There is no way I can define Record type for newly created table.
5. Otherwise, if I create a table definition from RootRecord, I cannot alter table name.

Is there a way to achieve desired behaviour with JOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to use the logical table (e.g. from code generation) and [apply table mapping at runtime](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/) to translate the table directly to the underlying partition.

E.g. you write:

```java
List<MyTableRecord> records = ...
ctx.batchUpdate(records);
```

But jOOQ doesn't update the `MY_TABLE` table, but the `MY_TABLE_1341` partition instead:

```sql
UPDATE my_table_1341 SET ...
```

This only works if you're writing to a single partition at a time.

Comment: thanks! that's a really nice trick =)